# sending encrypted password to LDAP server(Active Directory 2008)

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, md5, encryption

I could successfully login to AD with a clear-text password using the MD5 Digest authentication, additionally JNDI performs SASL encryption / Hash work on behalf of us, so everything works fine. However my problem is that, I want to hash my password on my own or any external device sends its passwords in encrypted form, so I must send the encrypted data to AD but it does not work when I change my password to encrypted. Is there any way to prevent JNDI to perform hashing the password?

"
  String original = originalPassword;

String pass = null;

MessageDigest md;

try {

md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

md.update(original.getBytes());

byte[] digest = md.digest();

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

for (byte b : digest) {

sb.append(Integer.toHexString((int) (b & 0xff)));

}

pass = sb.toString();

} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

}

Then I use this "pass" into my codes as:

env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, pass );

But it did not work:(

"

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Did you ever get answer to your question